# Как изменить значение элемента многомерного массива на 2 уровне в 1 подход?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

```
HashMap<String,  List<ArrayList>> baza = new HashMap<>();
```

Надо в массив `baza` по ключу и `индексу[0]` добавить  объект под названием `street_num`, после чего удалить последний индекс из ключа

Сейчас используется способ с промежуточной переменной.

Но хотелось бы напрямую добавить объект в базу и убрать лишний без создания промежуточной переменной.

```
raion = baza.get("key" + num_raion);
raion.add(0, street_num);
raion.remove(raion.size() -1);
baza.put("key" + num_raion, raion);
raion.clear();

// "key" + num_raion - ключ для hashmap
// street_num - объект который надо добавить по принципу ключ.индекс
// последнее надо удалить в ключе последний индекс
```

Comment: Если в ключе удалить последний индекс то он перестанет быть ключом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
baza.computeIfPresent("key" + num_raion, (k, v) -> {
    v.add(0, street_num);
    v.remove(v.size() - 1);
});
```

И возможно, [связанный список](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) подошёл был лучше. По крайней мере избавил бы от уродливых конструкций `v.add(0, ...)` и `v.remove(v.size() - 1)`.